# How to remove rows based on counting occurences of labels in a dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a huge daatset with the schema below:

```
   text              label1   label2  label3  labelN
any string             1         0      1        1
oasjdaskd              1         1      0        1
fghfghfh               1         0      0        0
```

The columns `label1 to labelN` can be any name like `color`, `size`etc..

In the example above:  `label1 has 3 occurences`, `label2 has 1 occurences`,`labe3 has 1 occurences` and `labelN has 2 occurences`

**What I want to do:**  I want to set a `threshold=500` so if a label has `600 occurences` the code will delete 100 random texts rows and will do nothing with labels with less then 500 occurences.   **The problem is that a same text (or row) can have several labels assigned to 1.**

I know I have to show what I tried so far but to be honest I have no idea how to start this problem.

Another sample data:

```
print (df)
          text  label1  label2  label3  labelN
0  any string1       0       0       1       1
1   any string       1       0       1       0
2    oasjdaskd       1       1       1       1
3     fghfghfh       1       0       1       1

threshold=2
```

Comment: `code will delete 100 random texts rows` - so here if `threshold=2` it delete one row randomly? Or replaced by missing value?

Comment: Added new sample data, what is expected ouput if `threshold=2` ?

Comment: Please explain more, what do you mean by deleting. Deleting a row will delete rows for all labels indepedent of their thresholds. Row number will be same for all columns whatever you do. Not clear. Based on your final sample data, give us desired output in case `threshold=2`.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to delete 100 random rows if threshold > 'n'. Say label 2 and 3 have more than the threshold 'n', label 1 and 4 are below the threshold. After iterating through columns, label 2 is identified with higher occurrences than threshold, we delete 100 random rows, now should we do delete 100 rows for label 2 or should we check for the condition again?